# What is the most efficient way to optimize a filter based on parameters on a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Right now I have something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetFilteredInformation]
    @pItem nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @pCity nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @pSerialN nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @pPromise datetime = NULL,
    @pSalesOrder nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @pLineNumber int = NULL

    DECLARE @vQuery nvarchar(max)

    IF (@pItem IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @vQuery += 'AND ITEM LIKE '' + @pItem + ''' 
    END

    IF (@pCity IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @vQuery += 'AND CITY LIKE '' + @pCity + ''' 
    END
```

... and so on, so in the end I'll have

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 1 = 1 + @vQuery
```

I think this is going to work, but it doesn't seems efficient to me. Is there a way to optimize this process and filter information with multiple parameters, with the option of some of them being null?

Comment: **WARNING**: Your code is *dangerous*. You are **injecting** parameters into your dynamic statement, not parametrising them. This is ***especially*** worse as you  are giving someone malicious 8GB (or 4 billion characters) to play with.

Comment: I suggest having a read of [catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [An updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Comment: Also, creating an object with a `.` in it's name is, in truth, a *terrible* idea. `.` is to denote a part separator; it should not be used in object names. Doing so means you *must* delimit identify the object name, and it is very confusing to look at.

Comment: Great examples in both of your articles! I really appreciate the feedback and I enjoyed reading them, specially the second one. About the dot, it was a typo, already edited the question to fix that

Comment: This particular method for kitchen-sink queries is actually the most efficient, just you need to make sure to pass the actual data parameters all the way through, using `sp_executesql`, do not inject them

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: *"About the dot, it was a typo"* But the `sp_` prefix is *also* a problem and should not be used.

Comment: As @Charlieface said, the above way (with properly parametrised dynamic statements) is the most efficient, as a different query will be generated for each variety of parameters needed. Those plans will be cached, and thus queries that frequently have the same set of parameters have a plan that they can use. The alternative method, which uses a non-dynamic statement and has `RECOMPILE` in the `OPTION` clause is much easier to read (and write) but forces the RDBMS to create the plan *every time* the query is run; which is likely not costly but could still at least at a couple of ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient method to do this type of [*kitchen-sink query*](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) is actually the way you are doing it now, except that you should properly parameterize each filter.

This is because a single plan will be cached for every possible combination of filters. This means that whenever that combination of filters is used again, even with different values, a cached plan will be used.

Whereas if you use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, a new plan is generated on every run. And `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` will usually just get you an overall not-that-great plan.

So you parameterize it with `sp_executesql`, like this

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetFilteredInformation]
    @pItem nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @pCity nvarchar(max) = NULL,
    @pSerialN nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @pPromise datetime = NULL,
    @pSalesOrder nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @pLineNumber int = NULL

DECLARE @vQuery nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE 1=1
';

IF (@pItem IS NOT NULL) 
    SET @vQuery += 'AND ITEM LIKE @pItem
';

IF (@pCity IS NOT NULL) 
    SET @vQuery += 'AND CITY LIKE @pCity
';

-- etc

-- for testing you can use PRINT @vQuery

EXEC sp_executesql
    @vQuery,

  N'@pItem nvarchar(max), 
    @pCity nvarchar(max),
    @pSerialN nvarchar(max), 
    @pPromise datetime,
    @pSalesOrder nvarchar(max),
    @pLineNumber int',

    @pItem = @pItem,
    @pCity = @pCity,
    @pSerialN = @pSerialN,
    @pPromise = @pPromise,
    @pSalesOrder = @pSalesOrder,
    @pLineNumber = @pLineNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to optimize a generic filter is to parse all items and condition of filter in a SQL dynamic query.

To do that, you need to have 2 XML parameters :

- The one that list the columns to be reached, in the form :
  date_begintown
- The other one with datatype and values, like : <val
  @type=date>2021-09-31<val @type=string>Paris

Then with these two strings that contains only the columns for searched values, you can build a query that will have a specific and optimizable WHERE predicate...

Comment: There are plenty of other ways other than using 2 XML parameters. Especially when XML doesn't allow for strongly typed values.

Comment: I did not say that XML is the only way... I did say that the only way to optimize it is to parse...

Comment: You say "you need to have 2 XML parameters", that implies that there aren't alternative options. There are, however, options where you *don't* "need" XML parameters at all.